# How to Query for COUNT on a join table and return records with BOTH count=0 AND count>0

Tags: mysql, join

I have a Products table and a Reviews table.
I want to write a query to return the COUNT and AVG of the reviews of each product.
**AND** if there are no reviews I want it to return 0/null for COUNT and AVG.

**product table**

```c
+--------+----------+
| prodId | prodName |
+--------+----------+
|   1    |  apple   |
|   2    |  banana  |
|   3    |  cacao   |
+--------+----------+
```

**review table**

```
+----------+----------+--------+
| reviewId |  prodId  | rating |
+----------+----------+--------+
|    1     |     1    |    1   |
|    2     |     1    |    1   |
|    3     |     2    |    5   |
|    4     |     2    |    5   |
+----------+----------+--------+
```

**this is what I want the result to look like:**

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
| prodId | prodName |   avg  | count |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
|   1    |  apple   |    1   |   2   |
|   2    |  banana  |    5   |   2   |
|   3    |  cacao   |   null |   0   |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
```

I am able to get the COUNT and AVG for the products with reviews

```
SELECT p.prodid, p.prodname, avg(r.stars), count(r.productid)
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN reviews r ON p.productid=r.productid 
GROUP BY p.productid
```

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
| prodId | prodName |   avg  | count |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
|   1    |  apple   |    1   |   2   |
|   2    |  banana  |    5   |   2   |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
```

I am also able to get the COUNT and AVG for a product with no reviews

```
SELECT p.prodid, p.prodname, avg(r.stars), count(r.stars)
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r 
ON (p.productid=r.productid) WHERE r.productid IS NULL
GROUP BY p.productid
```

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
| prodId | prodName |   avg  | count |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
|   3    |  cacao   |   null |   0   |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+
```

But I don't know if MySql has a way to query and count results that match and count results that have no match in one query.

Comment: That is not how you should write [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) in SQL.. SQL 1999+ Standards allows a optional feature which is called functionally dependent  which MySQL 5.7.5+ [supports](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) but not all databases supports this Oracle database for example is one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the `where condition` from your 2nd query

```
SELECT p.prodid, p.prodname, avg(r.stars), count(r.stars)
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews r 
ON p.productid=r.productid
GROUP BY p.productid,p.prodname
```

Comment: invalid `GROUP BY` unless SQL standard functional dependency on the `productid` column can be used..

Comment: @RaymondNijland can you explain more on your invalid GROUP BY?  I'm don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In practice for MySQL "LEFT JOIN" is the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN. OUTER keyword is optional.
To achieve the result you just need to do simple "LEFT JOIN" and to group by ID (or any other unique key):

```
SELECT 
    `p`.`prodId` AS `ID`, 
    `p`.`prodName` AS `Product`, 
    avg(`r`.`rating`) AS `AVG Rating`, 
    count(`r`.`reviewId`) AS `Vote Count`
FROM `products` AS `p`
LEFT JOIN `reviews` AS `r` ON `p`.`prodId` = `r`.`prodId`
GROUP BY `p`.`prodId`
```

Comment: invalid `GROUP BY` unless SQL standard functional dependency on the prodId column can be used..

Comment: *"In practice for MySQL "LEFT JOIN" is the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN. OUTER keyword is optional"* For every SQL database `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should work the same that is how the SQL definition is defined `<join type> ::= INNER | <outer join type> [ OUTER ]
<outer join type> ::= LEFT | RIGHT | FULL
` notice the `OUTER` in brackets which means optional keyword.